# Is it possible to use Telerik controls in a .Net 2 C# project?

Tags: c#, telerik

I am new to `Telerik`, and currently  using `Telerik 2013 Q2`, 
Is it possible to use `Telerik` controls in a `.Net 2 C#` project?
And if it is possible please tell me how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the Telerik site for minimum requirements for the 2013 Q2 release. Chances are, off the top of my head, that you'd need an older version to work with .net 2.0. The best approach would be to upgrade your project to .net 4.0 or 4.5, although I understand sometimes there are constraints and legacy projects where this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

From the Telerik website..

In order to use Telerik Reporting with .NET Framework 2.0/3.0/3.5 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2005/2008 you need Telerik Reporting Q1 2013 SP1 (7.0.13.426) or previous.